# Error Type { registry: TypeRegistry {}, initialU8aLength: 6 } when try to query ink! smart contract by @polkadotjs/api-contract

Tags: ink, smart-contract

My code:

```rs
const main = async() => {

    //Get wasm 
    // This file wasm I already build through "cargo contract build"
    let wasm = fs.readFileSync("../../res/incrementer.wasm");
    
    // API creation for connection to the chain
    const wsProvider = new WsProvider(process.env.WSS_PROVIDER);
    const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider });

    const keyring = new Keyring({ type: "ed25519" });
    const userKeyring = keyring.addFromMnemonic(process.env.MNEMONIC_PHRASE);
    

    // maximum gas to be consumed for the instantiation. if limit is too small the instantiation will fail.
    const gasLimit = 500000n * 1000000n;
    
    // a limit to how much Balance to be used to pay for the storage created by the instantiation
    // if null is passed, unlimited balance can be used
    const storageDepositLimit = null


    // Sign transaction to deploy contract
    //Define deployed contract with metadata + contract address
    const contract = new ContractPromise(api, metadata, '5GEMqSuQUCgYCoR5zZSzCX1of68o7F2pnyUapmkJhvbwT2BD');
    
    

    // Query value from contract
    const {result, output } = await contract.query.get(
    userKeyring.address,
    {
        gasLimit,
        storageDepositLimit,
    }
    );
    // check if the call was successful
    if (result.isOk) {
        // output the return value
        console.log('Success -> Value:', output.toHuman());
    } else {
        console.error('Error', result.asErr);
    }
 
}



main().catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

**Error:**

I can not query `get` function in `incrementer` smart contract through `@polkadot/api-contract`. I try to replicate this context in contracts-ui -> its working properly.

I have no idea why I encounter this issue

`Error Type { registry: TypeRegistry {}, initialU8aLength: 6 }`

**Environment:**

- Dependencies:

package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@polkadot/api": "10.1.3",
    "@polkadot/api-contract": "10.1.3"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

- Ink!: version 4
- Substrate node version: `0.9.36`
- My source `incrementer` ink! code: https://github.com/paritytech/ink-examples/blob/main/incrementer/lib.rs

Comment: Anyone used to get issue